# Plotly constant red line across bar chart multiple traces

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart

I'd like to have a constant red line go across an entire bar chart that indicates the average.  Here is an MRE.  So just imagine a dotted red line going across at 60 for each chart.  But I don't want the chart with more bars to scrunch together like it is currently doing.  Right now the red line scrunches the options fewer bars together so that the red line can go across the entire length of x1 so the output of x2 looks bad.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x1 = ['Alfred', 'Bob', "Cory", "Dave", "Eric", "Freddy", "Gary"]
x2 = ['Annie', "Barbara"]

y1 = [20, 30, 25, 40, 50, 60, 85]
y2 = [50, 70]

average = 60

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x1, y=y1))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x2, y=y2, visible=False))

fig.add_shape(
    type='line', line=dict(dash='dot', color='red'),
    x0=-1, x1=len(x1), y0=average, y1=average
)

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[go.layout.Updatemenu(
        active=0,
        buttons=list([
            dict(label="1",
                 method="update",
                 args=[{'visible':[False,True]}]),
            dict(label="2",
                 method="update",
                 args=[{'visible':[True,False]}]),]))])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reach it by adding this code to your script before `fig.update_layout()`

```
fig.add_shape(
    type='line', line=dict(dash='dot', color='red'),
    x0=-1, x1=len(x1), y0=average, y1=average
)
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without having the bars bunch up since different drop downs have different amounts of bars?  Like set the length of x1 to be from the traces?

Comment: I think you need to read documentation and look is there any way to do this.